# change text multiple times with a single button and hide the button for the last text

Tags: javascript, button, event-handling, hide, dom-events

I want to write a basic story where you just click next and the text changes.

I can change the text, but I don't know **how to hide the button**. Basically I want the `onclick` method to execute multiple functions, but not all at the same time, rather in a sequence

Code as below.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="div1">
      <p id="txt" class="txt1">OK, here wo go.</p>
    </div>
    <button id="btn_next" type="button">Next</button>
    <script>
      document.getElementById("btn_next").addEventListener("click", toggleText);
      function toggleText() {
        var textBox = document.getElementById("txt");
        switch (textBox.className) {
          case "txt1": {
            textBox.innerHTML = "This is text 1";
            swapClasses(textBox, "txt2");
            break;
          }
          case "txt2": {
            textBox.innerHTML = "This is text 2";
            break;
          }
        }
      }
      function swapClasses(elem, targetClass) {
        elem.className = targetClass;
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I have asked this question in many ways before posting this, but couldn't find an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to hide the button when the `<p>` class is `txt2`, which means the last text is shown, a simple way to do it would be this:

```
case "txt2": {
        textBox.innerHTML = "This is text 2"
        document.getElementById("btn_next").style.display = "none";

        break;
}
```

You could also store the button element to a variable `const btnEl = document.getElementById("btn_next")` so you don't get it twice.

Comment: Thank you so much, this works. Does that mean I can make other changes within this case? for example showing a list or appending a child?

Answer (score 0):

You can hide an element by setting its display to none like:
`nextBtn.style.display = 'none';

However, instead of using a switch statement, you can use an array of text values to drive your story as in the next answer

Answer (score 0):

Another approach to this is shown below.

```js
let counter = 0;
const displayed_text = [
  'Input text 1',
  'Input text 2',
  'Input text 3',
  'Input text 4',
];

// Assign DOM elements to variables
const btn_next =  document.getElementById("btn_next");
const text_display = document.getElementById("txt");

// Attach listener to button    
btn_next.addEventListener("click", toggleText); 

function toggleText() {
  counter += 1;

  if (counter <= displayed_text.length) {
    // Update displayed text
    text_display.innerHTML = displayed_text[counter -1];
  }

  if (counter === displayed_text.length) {
    // Hide button
    btn_next.style.display = 'none';
  }
}
```

The main advantage of this approach is that it makes it easier to go back multiple steps if you want.

Answer (score 0):

```js
    var story = [
        'OK, here wo go.',
        'This is text 1',
        'This is text 2',
        'This is text 3',
        'This is text 4'
    ];
    var nextBtn = document.getElementById("btn_next");
    function changeText() {
        var textBox = document.getElementById("txt");
        var chapter = Number(textBox.dataset.chapter);
        if (chapter < story.length - 1) {
            textBox.dataset.chapter = chapter + 1;
            textBox.innerHTML = story[chapter + 1];

            if ((story.length - chapter) <= 2 ) {
                nextBtn.style.display = 'none';
            }
        }
    }

    nextBtn.addEventListener("click", changeText);
```

```html
<div id="div1">
    <p id="txt" class="txt1" data-chapter="0">OK, here wo go.</p>
</div>
<button id="btn_next" type="button">Next</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

For cases like this, it can be beneficial to store the content in an array of objects (or fetch the content as JSON etc). Then, when the event handler is fired, it can simply increment (or decrement if you wish to have forward/backward) and determine whether the button should be visible or hidden. That appears to be the direction you're heading with the above code.

Example function:

```
function navigatePage(el){
  // Control the navigation by only allowing increment within range
  if (el != null){
    switch (el.target.getAttribute("id")){
      case "btn_next":
        if (curr_page < story.length){
          curr_page++;
        }
        break;
      case "btn_prev":
        if (curr_page > 1){
          curr_page--;
        }
        break;
      default: break;
    }
  }

  // Set the title and text to the current page contents
  // Arrays are zero-indexed, so "1" is actually "0", and so on
  story_title.innerHTML = story[curr_page - 1].title;
  story_content.innerHTML = story[curr_page - 1].text;

  // Show or hide nav buttons based on the current page
  // The following syntax is basically just a fancy "if-then" done in one line
  btn_prev.style.display = (curr_page > 1 ? "inline-block" : "none");
  btn_next.style.display = (curr_page < story.length ? "inline-block" : "none");

  // Update the page count element
  page_count.innerHTML = "Page " + curr_page + " of " + story.length;
//  document.getElementById("storycontent").innerHTML = curr_page + " - " + story.length;
}
```

Here is a working fiddle to demonstrate how it all works together:
https://jsfiddle.net/s0toz3L8/1/